# SignalR Context is null when I try to send data to client

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-active-directory, signalr.client

I've successfully added the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) to my app. I'm using the IN MEMORY approach.

The problem occurs when I try to use the SendChat: Context is null.

I do see the correct user name in my OnConnectedmethod.

Thoughts?

I'm using some Azure AD for security, I think it's working because I see the logged in user name when I connect (OnConnected)

Comment: Please show the code from you. Did you try to create a instance of the hub by yourself?

Comment: Ensure you are using same version both server and client side